# Change the color and font family for the "Table of Contents" in toc within book.cls (\contentsname)?

Tags: tocloft

By editing the book.cls file, I have tried several times without any success to alter the typeface for the \contentsname parameter, with the following custom color and font family: \cnavy \Huge\bfseries\sffamily.  This color combination and font family works fine for within-book section styles and toc entries, based on the modifications by the sectsty package, but I can't seem to alter the toc name's color and font family from within book.cls.

For example, I am using

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\cmrn\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\sectionfont{\cnavy\large\bfseries\sffamily}
```

But am obtaining the following toc results:

[image]

But I would like the \contentsname font family and color to be

```
\cnavy \Huge\bfseries\sffamily
```

Comment: book just does `\chapter*{\contentsname ...` so whatever colour and fonts you have specified for chapter will apply

Comment: You can obtain what you want with `titlesec` or `tocloft`. What is the command `\cnavy`?

Comment: ok, i'll look at titlesec.  I modified the OP with a pic showing that the sectsty package is successfuly changing the chapter and section headers in the toc, but not the \contentsname.

Comment: Try loading `tocloft` and writing in your preamble:  `\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\cnavy\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}`

Comment: It should be mentioned that you should not change `book.cls`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. @Bernard's suggestion worked!